# Error while creating alarm using openstack4j-3.0.3-withdeps.jar

Tags: openstack, ceilometer

I am facing an issue while creating the alarm with openstack4j-3.0.3-withdeps.jar.
Same issue observed with `openstack4j-3.0.5-20170507.171628-1-withdeps.jar`

```
CeilometerThresholdRule ceilometerThresholdRule = new CeilometerThresholdRule();   

Alarm alarm = Builders.alarm().name("high_Cpu1").description("testcpu-high")
        .type(Alarm.Type.THRESHOLD).thresholeRule(ceilometerThresholdRule).alarmActions(alarmActions).okActions(oKActions).isEnabled(true).build();

Alarm alarm2 = os
        .telemetry()
        .alarms()
        .create(alarm);
```

The Error is :
org.jboss.resteasy.client.ClientResponseFailure: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader of content-type text/plain;charset="UTF-8" and type null

Comment: which version of openstack you are using?

Comment: Hi , I am using openstack newton .[root@localhost ~]# nova-manage --version
14.0.3